# Safest deck on multi deck airplanes

Tags: safety, airbus-a380

It is a well known statistic that rear seats has higher survivability rates than front seats due to generally lower impact forces.

Double decks airplanes are not so common so statistics would probably be unreliable, especially since Boeing's only have a forward double deck.

Has any survivability study been made on that kind of aircraft, that include upper vs lower deck ?

I'm mostly interested in the a380 but other design are welcome as well.

Comment: Well, the JAL incident involved a 747 pretty sure, so you could probably assume a bit from that. Also, I would expect the same fundamental to be the same - the further forward you are, the less safe it would be.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm mostly interested into difference from upper and lower deck. Will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: The only A380 to be involved in an accident was the uncontained engine failure on Qantas flight 32, which caused no injuries. Therefore, there are no survivability statistics for the plane.

Comment: Statistics for this are meaningless.  1.  Crashes are extremely rare.  2.  In most crashes where anyone dies, all die.  The differences between different seats become noise and rounding errors.  Any statistic will be that in the freak case where one passenger survived, they were sitting in 38C.  This says nothing useful.  The correct statement is that for all practical purposes, all seats are equally safe.

Comment: @Simon Your second point is incorrect: The majority of airline crashes that involve a fatality also involve one or more survivors.

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to say as we don't have enough real-world examples.

Vertical impact forces would be lower on the upper deck as the lower deck acts something like a crumple zone and absorbs some of the acceleration.
That said, an evacuation from the upper deck can result in more injuries due to the longer, steeper, slide that's needed.

Comment: Additionally, when acting as a crumple zone, the lower deck gets crumpled by the upper deck.